# String Permutation Implemention

Tags: java, beginner, algorithm, combinatorics

The objective is simple: List all possible permutations for a given a String. I looked at some implementations from popular sources.  I decided to build this to the flow:

#### The Code for Review

```
    package com.progint;

    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    public class StringPermutations {

    public static ArrayList<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static String permutand;

    public static ArrayList<String> permuteString() {
        permutations = permuteString(permutand);
        return permutations;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> permuteString(String permutand) {
        ArrayList<String>  listOfPermutations = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(permutand.length()==1) {
            listOfPermutations.add(permutand);  
            return listOfPermutations;
        }
        /* Iterate over All character Values */
        for (int i=0; i<permutand.length(); i++) {
            String nextStringPermutation;
            if (i==0) { /* All characters following need to be permuted */
                nextStringPermutation = permutand.substring(i+1);
            }
            else {     /* All characters--not including the current base character-- need to be permuted */
                nextStringPermutation = "".concat(permutand.substring(0,i));
                if(i+1 < permutand.length()) {
                    nextStringPermutation = nextStringPermutation.concat(permutand.substring(i+1));
                }
            }
            /* Retrieve list of possible sub-permutations and build a list with all possibilities */
            ArrayList<String> innerListOfPermutations = permuteString(nextStringPermutation);
            for (String permutation : innerListOfPermutations)
                listOfPermutations.add(permutand.substring(i,i+1).concat(permutation));
        }
        return listOfPermutations;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> permutations;
        BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the string to permute");
        permutand = consoleReader.readLine();
        permutations = permuteString();
        System.out.println("The " + permutations.size() + " permutations are:");
        for(String permutation : permutations) {
            System.out.println(permutation);
        }
    }
}
```

I get a 'tarot deck being shuffled' vibe with this implementation.

#### My Inspirations (for Comparison)

The below is from Programming Interviews Exposed:

> ```
> void permute(String str){
>     int length = str.length();
>     boolean[] used = new boolean[length];
>     StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
>     char[] in = str.toCharArray();
>     doPermute(in, out, used, length, 0);
> }
> void doPermute(char[] in, StringBuffer out, boolean[] used, int length, int level) {
>     if( level == length ){
>         System.out.println( out.toString() );
>         return;
>     }
>     for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i ){
>         if(used[i]) continue;
>         out.append(in[i]);
>         used[i] = true;
>         doPermute( in, out, used, length, level + 1 );
>         used[i] = false;
>         out.setLength(out.length()-1);
>     }
> }
> ```

I also looked at [this very concise](//stackoverflow.com/q/7537791) implementation based on swapping.

Comment: You can only post code that you have written.

Comment: I believe that the first code block was not written by the post's author, but the second was.

Comment: Yes: I cited it as "The below is from Programming Interviews Exposed". This is usually how it's implemented, so.

Answer (score 4):

The sources of inspiration aren't really up for review, but they have a couple of things in common:

- They print the permutations, instead of storing them in a list. They could be adapted though.
- They recurse on a smaller string, but they do not create a physical string object with the new length. Characters are "removed" from the string not by physically removing them, but by changing bounds (the C++ implementation) or by marking them as "used" (PIE). Either way they manage to avoid doing a bunch of string processing.

But let's look at what you wrote, of course.

Passing values into functions via static variables, which `permuteString()` relies on, is a bad practice. `permuteString(String permutand)` is what I would have recommended as a replacement, you can call it directly from `main` and remove `permuteString()`.

Since you pass a physically shorter string down to the next level of recursion, on the way back up you need to prepend a character to all the results of the recursive call. It would be less awkward (and cost less string manipulation) to pass *down* a prefix which would be prepended before putting a string in the list.

Note that both of your sources of inspiration effectively do that, but in a way that also avoids the need to actively prepend the prefix, since it is already there. The C++ implementation passes that prefix in the part of the array that is implicitly treated as such, the PIE implementation passes the prefix in the buffer `out`.

The strings would end up in the list in their final form, with no further processing needed. That makes it simple to use a different strategy for the list: you can also pass *it* down, rather creating lots of new lists and copying the contents of one into the other all the time. That would result in a slightly annoying-to-use `void permuteString(String permutand, ArrayList<String> results)` rather than a `ArrayList<String> permuteString(String permutand)`, but you could easily implement the latter as a simple wrapper around the first (the awkward form would become only an implementation detail).

This logic to remove one character from the string,

> ```
> String nextStringPermutation;
> if (i==0) { /* All characters following need to be permuted */
>     nextStringPermutation = permutand.substring(i+1);
> }
> else {     /* All characters--not including the current base character-- need to be permuted */
>     nextStringPermutation = "".concat(permutand.substring(0,i));
>     if(i+1 < permutand.length()) {
>         nextStringPermutation = nextStringPermutation.concat(permutand.substring(i+1));
>     }
> }
> ```

Could be simplified substantially by using a `StringBuilder`, which offers the method `deleteCharAt(int index)`.

But I would recommend not doing that either, and instead following one of your sources of inspiration more closely, so that there is no need for such string manipulations. Doing it in a simpler way is still not as simple as not doing it at all.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the Edit. DIdn't really think including other code 'with citation' for comparison would ruffle so many feathers. I don't really consider them to be inspiring because they don't logically cohese in my mind with the algo(machine)-rithm(Rhythm). The bit swapping algorithm is neat, but it's very 'tinny'. Thanks for the coding suggestions.